# Test moment with enzyme

Tags: momentjs, enzyme

I'm trying to create a test and I can't make it work because when I do `moment("2017-09-10")` in test environment it does not create a Moment object. And because of that, the `isBetween` is always false.

This is my function

```js
export const filteredStatistics = (data, startDate, endDate) => {
  if(startDate === null || endDate === null) return data.toJS()

  return data.filter(element => {
    const date = moment(element.get("date"))

    return date.isBetween(startDate, endDate, "days", "[]")
  }).toJS()
}
```

This is my test

```js
import moment from 'moment'

describe('all dates', () => {
  it('returns original statistics', () => {
        const statistics = getOverviewStatistics('ctr')(overview)
        const statDate = moment(statistics.first().get('date'))
        const endDate = moment(statistics.last().get('date'))

        const current = filteredStatistics(statistics, statDate, endDate)
        const expected = statistics.toJS()

        expect(current).toEqual(expected)
      })
    })
```

I'm using "moment": "^2.19.1", "enzyme": "^2.9.1", "react": "^15.4.1".
Do you know how can I test it?

Prints with the difference between the object created running the code and running the test

The console.log:

```js
console.log('date:', date, 'startDate:', startDate, 'endDate', endDate, 'betweenResult:', date.isBetween(startDate, endDate, 'days', '[]'))
```

Running code:
[image]

Running test:

[image]

PS: I updated the code to use the given suggestions

I found the error: I was putting the end date 2016 and not 2017 u.u' Sorry and thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Does it throw an error?  How are you defining moment for testing?

Comment: @jmargolisvt It's not throwing an error. It's simply doesn't pass because returns a empy array. I'm defining moment like this: import moment from 'moment'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update to Moment 2.19.1.  There were issues with 2.19.0 that are probably impacting your import.
2. Don't use `moment(new Date(string))`.  That bypasses Moment's parsing capabilities and uses the `Date` object's parsing instead - which is inferior and often inconsistent.  Just use `moment(string)` instead, or `moment(string, format)` when applicable.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, but it did'nt work :( I updated the moment to 2.19.1 and removed the new Date(string) and got the same result :/ I found this article that explains a little bit about this issue, but I don't want to mock every date that I will use. The article: http://dancork.co.uk/2015/12/07/stubbing-moment/

Comment: A add some images to show the result running the code and running the test to help explains the problem

Comment: Your images are a bit confusing where they come from, but for the values I can see, `false` would be the correct response.  The `date` is not between the `startDate` and the `endDate`.

Comment: Sorry, I upload the wrong image. The point is, running the code it's created the moment object and running in test, the moment object it's not created. So because of that the isBetween is always false. At least this is my theory.

Comment: I found the error. I put the end time 2016 and not 2017 u.u thank you very much!